# Where can I find a list of connected devices for my Belkin G wireless modem router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I looked at the router's setup (`http://192.168.2.1/index.htm`) but can find no section for connected devices.

Answer (score 2):

http://192.168.2.1/lan_dhcp.html is where it is on my particular router.  But depending on your router model it may vary.

Comment: That link just redirected me back to the same setup page. Thanks any way.

Comment: If you include the model and firmware version of your router you will probably get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

with a belkin you look under 
use the link listed in above post
LAN > DHCP Client List 
it will show you every device using yoru router.

Comment: Which "Above post" is that?  Please edit your answer to clarify and perhaps tidy it up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

On the side menu under 'LAN Setup' there is a button labelled DHCP Client List. This will display your IoT connected devices.
This worked on 192.168.2.1/index.htm but you need to click DHCP Client List for it to show.

Jonathan :)

Answer (score 0):

Search for 'DHCP Client List' from the many options available in `192.168.2.1` (depends on your router).

**Note:** You might need to log in to your account if you want to see the list. **Default password** will be blank(depends on your router)
Then you will see a list of available devices with their IP address, Mac address and device name.

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.